# How to automatically create a svn tag in Teamcity

Tags: tags, teamcity

I would like to create svn tag in teamcity when the build is successful. I am using TeamCity Professional 8.1.4 (build 30168) and SVN version is version 1.7.8 (r1419691). I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The detailed instruction How to configure SVN labeling rules (with examples) is described in [TeamCity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/VCS+Labeling#VCSLabeling-SubversionLabelingRules).